# Cordova remote ios build fail with macincloud error:65

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors

I am trying to make a remote ios build for my one of my cordova apps, and I am always getting error.

```
1- Create a new cordova project in visual studio. 
2- Deleted all plugins. (include Whitelist)
3- Build solution.
4- Then got error 65 .
```

/cordova/build/tasks/22262/log line get a error and visual studio compiler with macincloud. 
Secure mode is false.

```
1>  Check dependencies
1>  Signing for "BlankCordovaApp3" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
1>  Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

1>  ** BUILD FAILED **
1>
1>
1>  The following build commands failed:
1>      Check dependencies
1>  (1 failure)
1>  Failed to build app for buildNumber 22262: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/user120288/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/22262/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-release.xcconfig,-project,BlankCordovaApp2.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7 arm64,-target,BlankCordovaApp2,-configuration,Release,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7 arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/user120288/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/22262/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/user120288/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/22262/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/user120288/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/22262/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-release.xcconfig,-project,BlankCordovaApp2.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7 arm64,-target,BlankCordovaApp2,-configuration,Release,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7 arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/user120288/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/22262/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/user120288/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/22262/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch - 1
1>  Error Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/user120288/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/22262/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-release.xcconfig,-project,BlankCordovaApp2.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7 arm64,-target,BlankCordovaApp2,-configuration,Release,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7 arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/user120288/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/22262/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/user120288/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/22262/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch - {1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some additional configuration to make Cordova work with Xcode 8 and iOS 10. I wrote about the workaround I used to resolve this:
https://dpogue.ca/articles/cordova-xcode8.html

To recap, you need to specify your developer team ID. In the next version of Cordova-iOS, you can do this with developerTeam in your build.json file. I have a hook available in the meantime.

You also need to set your code signing identity to "iPhone Developer", even for release builds. Do this with codeSignIdentity in your build.json.

You should not need to specify a provisioning profile, Xcode will automatically handle that when it has the team ID.

Hope that helps!